# "PersistentEntity must not be null" Exception with MongoDB and Spring Data REST

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Every attempt at creating a project with Spring Data REST and MongoDB has run into the same annoying issue.  Every test that tries access a REST endpoint results in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!`, thrown by the `PersistentEntityResource` builder method.  This implies that when the application context is started and `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` is initialized, that the `PersistentEntities` bean is empty.  Some example code:

```
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id private String id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    // Getters and setters
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "persons", collectionResourceRel = "persons")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "me.woemler.test" })
public class DataSourceConfig {

   @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
   public Mongo mongo() throws IOException {
     return new EmbeddedMongoBuilder().build();
   }

   @Bean
   public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo){
     return new MongoTemplate(mongo, "test-db");
   }

 }

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DataSourceConfig.class, RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class})
public class PersonTests {

  @Autowired private PersonRepository personRepository;
  @Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup(){
    personRepository.deleteAll();
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Joe");
    person.setAge(33);
    personRepository.save(person);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception{
      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/persons"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
  }

}
```

Stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource$Builder.<init>(PersistentEntityResource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource$Builder.<init>(PersistentEntityResource.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource.build(PersistentEntityResource.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:38)
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.createResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:209)
```

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Data MongoDB, and Spring Data REST with the latest Spring Platform version (Brussels-SR1).  Running the application with Spring Boot, I don't receive any errors, it is only when testing, using both the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `SpringRunner`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue and had to debug spring internals a lot

The reason of error - missing MappingConverter object in MongoTemplate.
When mongoTemplate bean is automatically created by Spring following constructor is used

```
public MongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter mongoConverter)
```

To solve this issue there are two options:

1) don't redefine MongoTemplate bean. You can use application.properties to specify database

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://hostname:27017/dbName
```

2) Autowire mongoConverter and use in creation of mongoTemplate

```
@Autowired
private MongoConverter mongoConverter;

public @Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter);
    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, where I am calling a method for read the values from the collection.

I was passing a blank string ("") and because of that it was giving me the exception mentioned.

After passing "null" explicitly the error was gone.

I don't know what the issue is with underline code but this is how I fix the issue.

Comment: There is a bug with "alike" function. If you pass any value, it failed. You will get the same error message. It has issue in "Example" class.